# Phaser - How to keep tween to complete when I change web tab?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phaser-framework

I have multiple tween in one group, but when I change web tab or switch tab to use another app. My tween is pause and running back when I change back to my phaser game so I have chaotic tween running.

Answer (score 1):

use this sitting

```
game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
```

please read the [doc](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Stage.html#disableVisibilityChange)

Comment: I read this doc and apply this code to my project but when I change tab and I came back my game tab after wait a long time (about 5m). My tween not complete, tween just pause and continuous. But change tab in a short time (about 1m) and back, my tween is fine. Thanks for reply!